# The problem with setuptools, anaconda prompt

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, setuptools

I'm developing a project using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRwflsS67ow). The command in 11:27 returns some errors.

```
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [68 lines of output]
      C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_03xpo02\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.

              By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.

              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
```

I tried `pip install setuptools==58.2.0` , `pip install .` ; but i have same error. My python version is 3.11.4

The full code of setup.py :

```
import os
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    'avro-python3', 'apache-beam','pillow','lxml','matplotlib','Cython',
    'contextlib2','tf-slim','six','pycocotools','lvis','scipy','pandas',
    'tf-models-official>=2.5.1','tensorflow_io','keras',
    'pyparsing==2.4.7',  # TODO(b/204103388)
    'sacrebleu<=2.2.0'  # https://github.com/mjpost/sacrebleu/issues/209
]

setup(
    name='object_detection',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    include_package_data=True,
    packages=(
        [p for p in find_packages() if p.startswith('object_detection')] +
        find_packages(where=os.path.join('.', 'slim'))),
    package_dir={
        'datasets': os.path.join('slim', 'datasets'),
        'nets': os.path.join('slim', 'nets'),
        'preprocessing': os.path.join('slim', 'preprocessing'),
        'deployment': os.path.join('slim', 'deployment'),
        'scripts': os.path.join('slim', 'scripts'),
    },
    description='Tensorflow Object Detection Library',
    python_requires='>3.6',
)
```

I think this error is about the setuptools library but I can't find any license_file in 'setuptools' library directory.

UPDATE : The problem is 'tf-models-official>=2.5.1' line, i have a issue with this library.

Comment: Edit your question and add the complete code. It looks like you need to replace license_file with license_files in your code but I can tell once you have updated the question with the code.

Comment: @MuhammadShamshadAslam i added it, can you review it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The main problem is 'tf-models-offical'. I researched some
and i found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9048#issuecomment-705420281). The codes working right now.